# Improved Bubble Sort, sometime work ,sometime it doesn't

Tags: java, sorting

This is my code for improved bubble sort using boolean.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class BubbleSort {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[5];
        int temp;
        boolean swap;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number!");
            array[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i<array.length-1; i++) {
            swap = false;
            for(int j = i + 1 ; j < array.length ; j++) {
                count++;
                if(array[i] > array[j]) {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                    swap = true;
                }
            }
            if(!swap) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

This code sometimes sorts it out for me but sometimes it does not.

I use count to find how many comparisons did the computer make so I know I'm using improved bubble sort and not the simple one.

First, I ask the user to input five numbers to sort.

If the numbers are: `5 4 3 2 1`

the sorted list is `1 2 3 4 5` and it shows the number of comparisons as `10`

or

if the numbers are: `1 2 3 4 5`

the sorted list is `1 2 3 4 5` comparison is `4` (this is correct as well because it only has 4 comparisons).

BUT

if the user enters: `1 3 2 4 5`

the sorted list is `1 3 2 4 5` (didn't change)  and the number of comparisons is `4`.

So it didn't swap 3 and 2.

What is wrong with my code?
Is it because of the break in the for-loop when I compare 1 and 3??

Comment: What happened when you tried debugging?

Comment: This isn't bubble sort.  This is selection sort.  Well, if it worked it would be.

Comment: @shmosel when i use the number like 1 3 2 4 5, the sorted list is still the same as before that mean it didn't swap and it says i only have 4 comparison.

Comment: @ huck_cussler this is bubble sort method, where you compared a number and number beside it and put the highest number at the end and if it already sorted before 10 comparison it stop immediately

Comment: @huck_cussler not true. selection sort looks for the smallest element each iteration. That said, you're right: this is not a bubble sort either since bubble sort swaps two adjacent elements if they're in the wrong order, while here the comparison is done between `array[i]` and `array[j]` which are not necessarily adjacent.

Comment: @Secret @alfasin The code above holds `i` fixed while iterating over `j=i+1` until `j` points at the last element in the array.  If the break were removed, the smallest element in (the remainder of) the array would end up at index `i` at every pass.  This is selection sort.  If, on the other hand, the code would have a single loop and would only compare elements adjacent to each other, it would be bubble sort.

Comment: @huck_cussler though `i` is static through the inner loop, in selection sort we start assuming that `array[i]` is the smallest and initialize another variable `index` to hold `i`, but throughout the iterations, whenever we find a smaller element we update `index` and we will do it again and again until the smallest element is found (and we'll swap it after finishing to scan the rest of the array, once, for the smallest element only) while here the swap operation is done immediately and there could be multiple such "swaps" over one iteration of the inner loop. This is not selection sort

Answer (score 1):

> what wrong with my code?

The problem is the `swap` variable and the fact that you're breaking out of the outer loop when it compared a single element to all the following and never swapping.

In the example you provided: 1,3,2,4,5
the outer loop ran with 1 and since it's the smallest the `swap` was never set to `true` and the logic broke before reaching the next element (3).

Fixed code (simply removing the "improvement"):

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[5];
    int temp;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number!");
        array[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1 ; j < array.length ; j++)
        {
            count++;
            if(array[i] > array[j])
            {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(count);
```

**Note**: as I wrote in the comments above, this is not bubble sort since bubble sort swaps two adjacent elements if they're in the wrong order, while here the comparison is done between `array[i]` and `array[j]` which are not necessarily adjacent.

Comment: Teacher want us to write a new bubble sort code using boolean

Comment: @Secret your question was not to do your HW for you, but rather help you find what was wrong with the implementation you've suggested. If you rather copy your HW than doing it by yourself, go for it: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Bubble_sort#Java

Answer (score 0):

The for loop conditions on the inner loop are not correct. The array comparison and swap logic were incorrect too. As mentioned in the comments, your code isn't doing a bubble sort.

**Hint:**

For the inner loop, `j` should start at 0 and loop as long as `j < array.length - i - 1`. `array[j]` and `array[j + 1]` should be swapped if `array[j] > array[j + 1]`.

Comment: do you know how to calculate the comparison the computer make?? i go back and type out this code without boolean(normal bubble sort code) and i got 16 comparison

Comment: @Secret In the worst case, the outer loop would execute `n - 1` times, and (assuming `n = 5`) the inner loop would execute 4 times, then 3, then 2, then 1 time, resulting in `(n - 1)*n/2` comparisons.

In the best case, the outer loop would execute once, and the inner loop would loop `n - 1` times, resulting in `n - 1` comparisons.